# Difference between: "susurro" and "murmullo"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Are `susurro` and `murmullo` interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Susurro"**  Is not necessary something bad/disturbing, is just the fact of speaking something in very low voice, generally directly to the ear of the other person.

**"Murmullo"** In general, implies some kind of disturbing action. Usually not directly to the ear.

For example:

- "Pedro y María murmullaban en la reunión"  → Implies the speaker was unhappy about the fact.
- "Pedro le susurró un secreto a María en la reunión" → This is just the fact.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'd add that when the sound comes from a person or some people, in "murmullo" you can't understand the words that the other person said while in "susurro" you usually can. As in "murmullo" you can't understand what he/they said that's why it's usually annoying.

Comment: @nacho4d: thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

Generally they're not interchangeable but there are some contexts where maybe can be used as synonims (I can't think of anyone right now). As you can see below *susurro* makes reference to a soft or quiet sound but murmullo has more the meaning of soft and continuous background noise. The difference is really subtle.

According to RAE:

> **[susurro](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=susurro).** (Del lat. *susurrus*).
>
> 1. m. Ruido suave y remiso que resulta de hablar quedo.
>
>    (Soft and quiet noise that results of speaking quietly)
> 2. m. Ruido suave y remiso que naturalmente hacen algunas cosas.
>
>    (Soft and quiet noise made naturally by some things)

For example you can say: *El susurro de las hojas agitadas por el viento*.

> **[murmullo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=murmullo).** (Del lat. tardío *murmurĭum*).
>
> 1. m. Ruido que se hace hablando, especialmente cuando no se percibe lo que se dice.
>
>    (noise made by talking, specially when what's being said it's not understood)
> 2. m. Ruido continuado y confuso de algunas cosas.
>
>    (continuous and blurred noise from some things)

For example you can say: *el murmullo del agua de un arroyo*.

Comment: @Javi thanks for the edit! how do you do the yellow marks?

Comment: You can just put the greater than symbol (">") before the line  or select the text and press the button "blockquote" which is in the edition toolbar (the buttons over the textarea in the edit mode).

Answer (score 0):

The same subtle difference exists in English between `whisper` and `murmur`.